# Android: HorizontalScrollView Scrolling Issue

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have a custom`HorizontalScrollView`, `LinearLayout` as a child, and an initial 9 custom views under the `LinearLayout`.

When I scroll to the right, I need to add 3 more child views to the `LinearLayout`, and then remove the first three children, such that only 9 child views are present at a time.

We added detection points based on view ids, in such a way that if the `currentViewId > lastChildId - 0.33f * viewSizeLimit` where `viewSizeLimit = 9`. If this is valid, that's the time we add/remove views from the `LinearLayout`.

First issue I encountered is that when I remove views from the `LinearLayout`, the children are shifted to the left. So if the `currentViewId = 7`, and the current view is on the detection zone so we add 3 views to the end, and remove 3 views from the front. So now the `currentViewId = 4` due to the shift.

We added `scrollBy` method of the `HorizontalScrollView` to compensate this view shift and works well if scrolling is not that fast.

Here's an example from the logs:

```
07-01 17:01:34.304: INFO/GTA(2476): currentViewId: 6
07-01 17:01:34.304: INFO/GTA(2476): Scroll Distance: 8
07-01 17:01:34.373: INFO/GTA(2476): currentViewId: 6
07-01 17:01:34.383: INFO/GTA(2476): Scroll Distance: 41
07-01 17:01:34.463: INFO/GTA(2476): currentViewId: 7
07-01 17:01:34.463: INFO/GTA(2476): Scroll Distance: 25
07-01 17:01:34.633: INFO/GTA(2476): Added new views to the end
07-01 17:01:34.643: INFO/GTA(2476): currentViewId: 4
07-01 17:01:34.653: INFO/GTA(2476): Scroll Distance: -1440
07-01 17:01:34.653: INFO/GTA(2476): Head View ID: 4 | Tail View ID: 12
07-01 17:01:34.673: INFO/GTA(2476): currentViewId: 7
07-01 17:01:34.673: INFO/GTA(2476): Scroll Distance: 22
07-01 17:01:34.733: INFO/GTA(2476): currentViewId: 7
```

Here's the log when scrolling/flinging the scrollview fast:

```
07-01 17:03:48.633: INFO/GTA(2476): currentViewId: 6
07-01 17:03:48.643: INFO/GTA(2476): Scroll Distance: 158
07-01 17:03:48.693: INFO/GTA(2476): currentViewId: 6
07-01 17:03:48.704: INFO/GTA(2476): Scroll Distance: 124
07-01 17:03:48.753: INFO/GTA(2476): currentViewId: 7
07-01 17:03:48.753: INFO/GTA(2476): Scroll Distance: 114
07-01 17:03:48.914: INFO/GTA(2476): Added new views to the end
07-01 17:03:48.914: INFO/GTA(2476): currentViewId: 4
07-01 17:03:48.914: INFO/GTA(2476): Scroll Distance: -1440
07-01 17:03:48.914: INFO/GTA(2476): Head View ID: 4 | Tail View ID: 12
07-01 17:03:48.974: INFO/GTA(2476): currentViewId: 10
07-01 17:03:48.974: INFO/GTA(2476): Scroll Distance: 1843
07-01 17:03:49.194: INFO/GTA(2476): Added new views to the end
07-01 17:03:49.204: INFO/GTA(2476): currentViewId: 7
07-01 17:03:49.204: INFO/GTA(2476): Scroll Distance: -1440
07-01 17:03:49.204: INFO/GTA(2476): Head View ID: 7 | Tail View ID: 15
07-01 17:03:49.253: INFO/GTA(2476): currentViewId: 14
07-01 17:03:49.264: INFO/GTA(2476): Scroll Distance: 1866
07-01 17:03:49.403: INFO/GTA(2476): Added new views to the end
07-01 17:03:49.414: INFO/GTA(2476): currentViewId: 11
07-01 17:03:49.414: INFO/GTA(2476): Scroll Distance: -1440
07-01 17:03:49.414: INFO/GTA(2476): Head View ID: 10 | Tail View ID: 18
07-01 17:03:49.463: INFO/GTA(2476): currentViewId: 18
07-01 17:03:49.463: INFO/GTA(2476): Scroll Distance: 1551
07-01 17:03:49.703: INFO/GTA(2476): Added new views to the end
07-01 17:03:49.713: INFO/GTA(2476): currentViewId: 15
07-01 17:03:49.713: INFO/GTA(2476): Scroll Distance: -1440
07-01 17:03:49.713: INFO/GTA(2476): Head View ID: 13 | Tail View ID: 21
```

From the logs, it can be seen that the `HorizontalScrollView` scrolls by itself by definitely huge amounts (ie. 1843, 1866, 1551). The `-1440` value we're seeing is the `scrollBy` compensation we added to set the proper view visible in the viewport.

So problem now is that I can't seem to find out why the `HorizontalScrollView` scrolls itself by such large distances. Any reason for this occurrence?

Is there any better way of implementing this aside from using a `HorizontalScrollView`?

Should I consider using a game engine for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest using a Gallery, which is basically a horizontal ListView.

The idea is that a SpinnerAdapter implementation provides the gallery with a view with a width of 1/9th of the area but is otherwise a standard implementation. This would give you unlimited scrolling that I think (assuming I've understood your requirements) would give you the effect you're looking for. It would also have the happy side-effect of snapping into position.

I hope that's helpful.

Comment: Thanks Phillip. We already thought about using `Gallery` but the snapping effect is what we're also trying to avoid. Basically, the scrolling should be as smooth as possible.